# Carbon subtracting Datetime from Carbon::now()

Tags: php, datetime

I want to use this Carbon function: 
Carbon::now()->subDays(5)->diffForHumans()

And I need to create the correct integer.

I am loading a string with a Datetime, which I want to subtract in Laravel like this:

```
 $datetime = $score->created_at;
```

Then I save the current Time into a variable

```
 $now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

This is what I get:

```
 echo $now . '<br>'; // 2014-07-13 22:53:03
 echo $datetime;     // 2014-07-12 14:32:17
```

But when I want to subtract one from another I get the following error:

```
 echo $now - $datetime;
```

> Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to int

Any help here would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but this works:

```
$score->created_at->diffForHumans(\Carbon\Carbon::now())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the date format just use the format function

```
$now = Carbon::now();

$score->created_at->diffForHumans($now)->format('Y-m-d');
```